# How to get the format of a date in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to get the format of a date.

Like I have a date as `2012-07-24`

I need a method that will return me a string like
`yyyy-MM-dd`

is it possible?

Comment: What would you expect it to give you with "06/07/2012"? Is that dd/MM/yyyy or MM/dd/yyyy?

Comment: Well exactly. You can't start trying to work out a *code* solution before first understanding the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: "I have a date as 2012-07-24" --- "return me a string like yyyy-MM-dd" Seems to me like you already have it in the format that you want. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Could you clarify? You want a string returned from a date, but how is that date going to be stored? Without that information to start with, we can't really help you convert from an unknown data type into a String...Also, why are all those answers being downvoted??? Provide some feedback at least as to what you would like instead. Geez.

Comment: Cancer gave me the answer and he understood what I wanted, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You cannot parse a String to form a Date because of the ambiguity
>   associated with the interpretation of the Date string. For example,
>   consider the date presented as "10/12/2009". One can interpret it as
>   10th of December and also as 12th of October. You can not map this
>   string to a definitive date value unless you know the pattern it
>   conforms to.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to go backwards from a date to get the format from it.  It is possible in some ways but only up to a point.  Dates like 2012-01-02 can be either interpreted as Jan 2nd or Feb 1st depending on standards, so your parsing of it would be ambiguous.  But dates like 2012-07-13 are definitely defined as July 13th.  I would go back and ask why you need to get the format and is there another way to achieve what I need

Answer (score 0):

Long time ago, I made a custom method where I did use substring to obtain specific value from the content of a String. See below for the code:

```
public class Initialise {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Test: " + reverseDate("14-10-2012"));
    }


    /********************************************************************
    * REVERSE DATE                                                       *
    *********************************************************************/
    public static String reverseDate(String tempDate){

        String year     = tempDate.substring(0, 2);
        String month    = tempDate.substring(3, 5);
        String day      = tempDate.substring(6, 10);

        String rdate    = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;

        return rdate;
    }
}
```

It's very simple if you can think logically and I also hope that this did help you solve the problem. Mark correct if you're done.